# Sequential process navigation

Tags: process

We are currently designing a mobile app which maps a complex sequential process. We have considered

- breadcrumbs
- train stops
- wizard
- card/ accordion
- tabs

so far. None is comprehensively satisfying because each step leads into a miniprocess of its own which needs to be visualised. In usability evaluations people keep getting lost (Where am I? What would be the next step? How do I get back?)

So, there are three questions to the community:

1. Are there any more process UI features beyond the mentioned ones?
2. Which should be used in which situation?
3. How would you lead through a process including sub processes on a limited screen?

Following JonW's advice here is an example screen that illustrates the complexity of the process.

[image: Example screen illustrating a complex process.]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's quite hard to visualise this problem when it's described at such a high-level. Are you able to give it more context, some examples of the process itself, or perhaps show us a 'Lorem Ipsum' version of the actual sequence you have?

Comment: I think this is the kind of question companies pay thousands of dollars to consultants for. It's extremely complex, and it doesn't have a clear solution without A LOT of additional information, and each possible solution will require a lot of testing as well. At first sight, I'd say there's an Information Architecture issue, but it's impossible to know without more information, and I think it's way out of the scope of this site.